# Sending Images Using WhatsApp api in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net

i ve searched a lot on net regarding this but i didnt receive  any solution.

this is my method

in a button click event of asp.net.
Please help me i am running this on localhost.
I dont know where i am going wrong.i am not even getting any error , the method is getting executed but image is not getting sent to receiver.

```
private void Send()
{
 string from = "+91*********";
 string password = "****";
 string nickName ="****";
 string to = "+91" + PhoneNumberTextBox.Text;
 string message = MessageTextBox.Text;

 byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\myPc\\Downloads\\a.jpg");

 WhatsAppApi.WhatsApp wa = new WhatsAppApi.WhatsApp(from, password,    nickName, false, false);

 wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
 {
    wa.SendMessage(to, message);

    wa.SendMessageImage(to + "@s.whatsapp.net", img,  ApiBase.ImageType.JPEG);
 };

 wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
 {

 };
 wa.Login();
};

 wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
 {

 };
 wa.Connect();
}
```

Comment: You might be better suited with this one to get off to the vendor for support with this.  Otherwise, you could use Fiddler or similar to track the outbound communication.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to logged in on it. Try below code hopefully it is helpful to you.

```
  wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
        {

            wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
            {
                wa.SendMessage(to, message);
                wa.SendMessageImage(to + "@s.whatsapp.net", img,  ApiBase.ImageType.JPEG);};

            wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
            {

            };
            wa.Login();
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response.It seems i had forgotten to mention that logged in code here, but I have written that also in my project,but then also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Google changed chrome and Chrome web driver topology we may use another browser and web driver..

Install Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver from NuGet and then you can do the following:

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).